# Password checker from list

Tags: python, passwords

I'm trying to build a function that will check if a password is valid. It has the usual constraints which include - must contain an upper letter, lower letter, a number and punctuation, which I have code for. But the punctuation can only be from a given list. The punctuation is !@#$%&()-_[]{};':",./<>?

```
def password_check(string):
    punct = ['!', '@', '#', '$', '.', '%', '&', '(', ')', '-', '_', '[', ']', '{', '}', ';', "'", ':', '"', ',', '.', '/', '<', '>', '?']
    val = True

    if len(string) < 8:
        val = False             

    if not any(char.isdigit() for char in string):   
        val = False

    if not any(char.islower() for char in string ):
        val = False

    if not any(char.isupper() for char in string):
        val = False

    if not any(char in whitelist for char in string):
        val = False

    if any(char == " " for char in string):
        val = False

    return val
```

HelloWorld1! should return True while HelloWorld1!* should return False. How do I make sure the non-alphanumeric characters are from the list?

Comment: What is the question here? What is the problem? Please be more specific

Comment: “.. for .. in ..” is not a filter operation. A non-empty sequence is never false-y. Thus “not false-y” is always true. Try to use an *actual* for loop statement, with the condition inside: “for char in password: if (char..) ..”

Comment: Alternatively, see https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/ for how to use list comprehension correctly here, as a filter, eg: invalid_chars = [c for c in password if is_invalid(c)]; if invalid_chars: ..

Comment: you create list of values `True/False` but `not` will only check if list is not empty but it will not check if there is `False`. You many need `if not all(your_list): val = False` to check if one of element is `False`. Or even without `if/else` - `val = all(your_list)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```py
def password_check(string):
    whitelist = set("!@#$.%&()-_[]{};':\",./<>?aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYzZ0123456789")

    if set(string) <= whitelist:
        #Password is valid
        val = True
    else:
        #Password isnt Valid
        val = False
    return val
```

Comment: I already have that code, that only checks if there is at least one of those characters in the password. I want to make sure that the punctuation is from the list. eg. HelloWorld1! is True but HelloWorld1* is False, because * is not in my list.

Comment: @MojoMike My answer does make sure that the only punctuation allowed is the punctuation from the list. I just ran it again and ``HelloWorld1!`` returned True and ``HelloWorld1*`` returned False

Comment: Sorry, I meant HelloWorld1! returns True but HelloWorld1!* should be False but is returning True.

Comment: @MojoMike I've fixed my answer and now it should work

Comment: Hold on theres still a problem

Comment: @MojoMike I've finally figured it out. Give it a try now

Comment: I added it to my code, but then the other if statements didn't work anymore. But your code does work, I just need to get everything to work now. I updated my question, so all of my code is there now.